# Sitecore, Mistakenly clicked on `Rebuild Solution` instead of `Build Solution`

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I was working on my project in `Visual Studio 2013` and I mistakenly clicked on `Rebuild Solution`. I am getting following exception, I don't have any idea how to fix it. Please suggest.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

**Could not resolve type name:** `Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand, Sitecore.Buckets (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).`

**Description:** `An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

**Exception Details:** `System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand, Sitecore.Buckets (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).`

**Stack Trace:**

---

**Exception: Could not resolve type name:** `Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand, Sitecore.Buckets (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).`

```
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +129
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +428
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +67
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +141
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +694
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +577
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +296
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +420
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert) +185
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabases() +168
Sitecore.Data.Managers.HistoryManager.InitializeEventHandlers() +49
Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeManagers.Process(PipelineArgs args) +16
(Object , Object[] ) +80
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +365
Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +172
Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +516
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +530
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
           System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
           System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand, Sitecore.Buckets (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618692
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458309
```

Comment: Sounds like you are working from within the webroot. You'd be better moving to a webdeploy model, which will stop this issue happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31hDPuyijwo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rebuild will clean your `/bin` folder and if you had your Sitecore dll's stored there but you have not referenced them from another path, you will lose them.

You could download the Sitecore files again and copy the dll's to a folder (ie: `/depends/sitecore`) and add references them in your project. This way the dll's are copied to the bin folder when you build the solution.